# facebook post issue in IOS

Tags: react-native, fbsdksharedialog

```
const sharePhotoContent = {
              contentType: 'photo',
              photos: [
                {
                  imageUrl: `data:image/png;base64,${base64Image}`,
                  userGenerated: false,
                }
              ],

            };
            ShareDialog.canShow(sharePhotoContent).then(
              (canShow) => {
                if (canShow) {
                  return ShareDialog.show(sharePhotoContent);
                }
              }).then((result) => {
                console.warn('result on facebook',result)
                if (result.isCancelled) {
                  console.log('Share cancelled');
                  setIsDisabled(false)
                } else {
                  setPlatform({ ...platform, isFacebook: true })
                  setIsDisabled(false)
                  console.log('Share success');
                }
              }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('Share fail with error: ' + error);
              })
```

In this code, I want to share posts in IOS but it shared posts on Facebook but not shown in the Facebook timeline or stories
USING LIBRARY:

```
import { ShareDialog } from 'react-native-fbsdk-next';
```